# Decompose a Hermitian Operator into Eigenvalues and Projectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

Quantum Computing - A Gentle Introduction by Eleanor Rieffell and Wolfgang Polak states on p57 :

> Any Hermitian operator $O$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ can be written as $O = \sum_j \lambda_j P_j$ where $P_j$ are the projectors for the $\lambda_j$-eigenspaces of $O$

An example operator is:

$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$

which can be considered as split into eigenvalues and projectors:

- 0 $|00\rangle\langle00|$
- 1 $|01\rangle\langle01|$
- 2 $|10\rangle\langle10|$
- 3 $|11\rangle\langle11|$

Is there a mathematical procedure (and a corresponding Mathematica function) which can be used to transform the Operator into the set of Projectors? The *Eigensystem* function will provide the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but it's not clear to me how that result is related to the required Projectors (which in the example I've given are 4-by-4 matrices). My overall objective is that, given an Operator, I can determine which states a system may end up in after a measurement and what the classical probability of each result is.

Comment: I think you just need to diagonalise the operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great deal simpler than you think. I think you're probably just having one of those bad days where you forget a very basic fact.

Let $X$ be any vector written as a column, here one of the eigenvectors. Then the projector onto its direction is $\hat{X} \otimes \hat{X}^* = \hat{X}\,\hat{X}^\dagger$, where $\dagger$ is the complex conjugate transpose and $\hat{X} = X / \|X\|$ is the unit vector. This operator acts from the left on a state $Y$, so that the whole operation is

$$Y\mapsto (\hat{X}\,\hat{X}^\dagger)\,Y = \hat{X}\,(\hat{X}^\dagger\,Y)$$

So $\hat{X}^\dagger\,Y$ is a scalar: the projection of $Y$ onto the unit eigenvector. This multiplies $ \hat{X}$ to give an eigenvector with the length of the projection.

Mathematica is a bit quirky here: If you write the vector $X$ as an array $X = \{x1,x2,x3\};$ then you'll either need to call

$$\mathrm{TensorProduct}[X,\mathrm{Conjugate}[X]]/(X.\mathrm{Conjugate}[X])$$

(which makes perfect sense) or (the weird one) to use the conjugate transpose, you need to write $X$ as $X = \{\{x1\},\{x2\},\{x3\}\}$ and then the function $\mathrm{ConjugateTranspose}$ will work and your projector is 
$$X.\mathrm{ConjugateTranspose}[X]/(X.\mathrm{Conjugate}[X])$$

(you need to write $X$ as an array of one-element rows so that $\mathrm{ConjugateTranspose}$ can work)

Comment: There is also [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) for them 'nominators.

Comment: I'm still a long way from fluent so I still need a push with the simple stuff :)

In terms that are more familiar to me, you're saying: $|X\rangle\langle X|$ , which makes sense.

Comment: I now see what the "Measurement in Quantum Mechanics" Wikipedia page is saying too. I don't need to bother constructing the Projectors to calculate the probabilities. For the state $|\psi\rangle$ I need the quantity:

$|P_j|\psi\rangle|^2$ or $\langle\psi|P_j|\psi\rangle$ but since that's $\langle\psi|X\rangle \langle X|\psi\rangle$ I suppose I can just use the eigenvector and the state vector and calculate |$\langle X|\psi\rangle|^2$ (assuming normalised vectors).